# Can preventing a computer fan from turning cause damage?

Tags: fan

I got myself a hot-swap hdd bay -from what I thought to be a reputable brand- to fit in a 5.25 slot of my new (very silent) build. However this rack has a small 40mm fan at the back that generates way too much noise; it's unbearably irritating.

I proceeded to unscrew the fan and it turns out that the fan itself is silent; it's from it being mounted to the rack that the noise is generated. So until I figure out how to eliminate this noise, probably by inserting some rubber here and there, I'm considering flat out blocking the fan so it doesn't turn.

Can that cause damage to the fan, the PSU, or anything really?

Comment: Since you have already removed it, fit some rubber washers and put it back - hopefully it will show the improvement you suggest. But if it is not there / running, then the hdd may well overheat.

Comment: Thanks for responding but you evaded my question :)
Fixing the noise is indeed what I intend to do but that'll take me a few days. I'm not too worried about the drives overheating. My build has very good airflow; plus I've seen other such units that don't sport a fan. I am just wondering if it can cause harm to physically block the fan

Comment: I answered one of your several questions with "then the hdd may well overheat". Why do you want to "physically block" the fan? It would be simpler just to disconnect it.

Comment: OK, I was thinking of direct damage from the fan being blocked (e.g., damage to the fan motor trying to rotate the fan) rather than indirect damaged resulting from the fan not doing what it's supposed to do.
The fan connector inside the unit is very difficult to access. I _could_ maybe reach it with thin pliers and pull but it would be a risky procedure and it would be virtually impossible to plug it back in. Otherwise I would have to completely dismantle the unit but, again, I'm not sure I could put it back together.

Comment: *"fan itself is silent"* -- Presumably you mean in free air.  The noise when the fan is installed could be (a) mechanical vibration (as you suspect), or (b) air turbulence,  or (c) a combination of both.

Comment: Stopping a fan's motor from spinning **will eventually burn out the fan motor**.  No other damage to the system should occur.  You could get a water cooler, and that could be silent.

Comment: ah so that is indeed what I wanted to know. That is unfortunate.
@sawdust indeed, it is silent in free air. when I start putting it back, there's vibration noise due to contact with the unit. And when I push it all the way against the 'exhaust' hole, there's a strong wooshing sound from air turbulence. I should be able to fix the vibration with some rubber padding but eliminating the turbulence is another story. Aside from somehow slowing it down...

Answer (score 0):

No harm will come to your computer.  The fan is for the hard drive in the hot swap bay.  It is there to cool the hard drive, as the bay might cause heat to not dissipate as well.  Still, the odds of drive failure is very low, it is unlikely to generate that much heat.

Comment: Thanks. I also don't think heat generation is an issue. I just wouldn't want the fan to like 'fry' because it was blocked since, down the road, i'd like to just fix the noise and let it run.

Comment: @user2877959 you might be able to unplug the wire.  worst case, desolder it.